# Sending coordinates from google maps to other application

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to send coordinates (lon & lat) from Google Maps to my application.

I was trying to do this by using share i Google Maps and teh pointing my application.

I know that by using share GM sens text with and address and link to map.
 Since there are no coordinates in open text, I was trying to get them from link.

Link is in shortUrl version (eg. goo.gl/maps/n8HffcEcMeG2) by I was able to transform it to longUrl version. But in this version there are still no lon & lat visible.

Howevwer when I click this link (short or long version) and map is opened in the browser the link changes after ~1sec to antother (3rd) version that contains lon and lat.

Any suggestions how I can the coordinates from shortUrl / longUrl ?
Or are there any other methods to send coordinates form Google Maps to other application?

Comment: Have you tried using a google map inside your app instead of using the google maps inside your app? There are many guides on google map integration inside your own app

Comment: My app is based on different map server (not Google). I am trying to add possibility for user to send coordinates from Google Maps to my app, so that my app shows the same place on its own map.